# Resilient Video Codec (Power Loss)

Tags: c#, .net, video, codec

For the system i'm building I need a video codec that is resilient to power loss - i.e. If the power were to be cut, the video would still need to be playable from what was left on the flash disk.

(Car PC project, the computer is shut off immediately upon key removal, and if power is lost during an accident).

Can anyone suggest a suitable codec (and encoder compatible with .net), ideally with low processing power required (Worst case scenario flash disk can write at ~6mbps)?

Comment: I'm not sure how it would handle power loss, but the game-oriented codec [bink](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkmain.htm) tends to be pretty good at plowing through errors and going on its way. It's also reasonably efficient, at least on the CPU side (not sure about disk). It's proprietary, unfortunately, and I don't know terms.

Answer (score 2):

Any codec is playable upto the point that the power loss. The key is the right container.Use a transport stream. [TS]. It will play just fine.   Containers like mp4 and 3gp are not right.

If you think logically, any streaming format is playable. Because the stream can be cut off at anytime. TS streams were designed for streaming and hence are perfectly playable to the point that you loose your power. The video and audio codec you have inside will not matter. Choose H.264 and aac for good compression features.

Webm, mjpeg are also streamable formats.

Answer (score 1):

At the codec level all you really need to worry about is the presence of B Frames.

H.264 Baseline or Constrained Baseline profile will work.  This is space efficient, but processing intensive.

MJPEG would also work though is very takes a lot of space, but very little CPU.

As user1559108 correctly points out the container is another matter.  MP4 and variants will likely be repairable its still not a great choice here.

In fact if you want to make sure you get every frame you may want to just write a raw stream and (if you have audio) worry about muxing after the fact since the muxing will inevitably introduce some latency.

Comment: He does not need to worry about the B frames as well. The B picture has to reference the pictures that are already out there in the stream. So no issues there too. Eg.If decode order is IPBBPBBIBBPBBP each B picture has the reference picture already written. Let me know if there is a scenario where this is wrong. [Can arbitary display order of H.264 screw it up in some form?]